# UPDATE with GROUP BY without selecting something from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-update

I have generated random postalcodes and I want to `UPDATE` them into my table. My table has some random generated streetnames in it, but there are duplicates, since it simulates a logging thing from a city.

How can I use the `UPDATE` statement to insert the same postalcode to every street name?

Example:

```
STREET   | POSTAL
--------------------
Street 1 | 12345
Street 2 | 54321
Street 1 | 12345
Street 3 | 67891
```

Semi-pseudo code:

```
UPDATE TABLE_CHARGE SET COLRW_POSTAL =  @randomPostalcode
GROUP BY COLRW_STREET
```

To clarify:
I do NOT need to `SELECT` anything. I only need to `UPDATE` one column.
The `GROUP BY` clause should group the streetnames, so that every streetname has it's own psotalcode. Since there are duplicates, I cannot just run the `UPDATE` statement because everything will get a random postalcode.

If anything is unclear, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add what output you need?

Comment: I don't understand what the `GROUP BY` bit is meant to be doing here. If you run the query with just the `UPDATE` and `SET` clauses, what does it do wrong for you?

Comment: @Ullas Thanks for responding! the output I want is that every streetname has the same postalcode. If I run the above query every row in my table has different postalcode.

As I mentioned, there are duplicate streets in there, because it needs to simulate a logging from a fantasy city (for students to use).

My problem is, that when I run the `UPDATE` statement, every row gets another postalcode.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for responding! The `GROUP BY` clause should be doing the following:
Group the streetnames from the table and after that set the postalcodes. So that every street has the same postalcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE_CHARGE SET COLRW_POSTAL = (ROUND((RAND()* 10000),0))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Could you explain what you are trying to do here?
Either I do not get it properly, or you misunderstood my question.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Didn't you want a random number to be assigned as the same postalcode for every street name in your question?

Comment: I have random postalcodes. I also have 1150 records of streetnames. However, there are only 250 unique streetnames. I did this on purpose. Right now I want to `UPDATE` my postalcodes. It takes some random numbers. I want to update the postalcode, but I want for every distinct streetname 1 postalcode. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda figured it out. I made a table with random street names and random postal codes in it en exported that to my final table.

Thanks for you advice!